# Sharing a Visual Studio resouce between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution that is mostly C# and a few legacy C++ projects.

I have a resource in the Resource.resx file that I use in a C# project and would like to use in the C++ project as well.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You can parse .resx's XML to get stuff in C++. Although, I'm not sure if it will be a good idea.

Comment: That sounds like it may cause more problems later on.